# How define an HTML element on the side and reference it later on?

Tags: html

I am low level programmer and new to HTML.

I have the html body which has the structure of my page.

one of the elements in this body is a long dropdown list. I was thinking that it makes sense to have this list defined separately, at the bottom of the file or at the top, and only reference it inside the body, so the full structure size stay reasonable and easy to read.

Is this something I can actually do? is this a reasonable request?

Comment: Sounds like you want to bind a select to JSON data.

Comment: Unless you want to read and interpret the HTML markup yourself instead of a web browser, you should not care about how it looks. Of course, you could declare the select options separately and populate your select with Javascript, or even load the options as an external resource, but that would only make sense if there is a gain (for example if you do not have to load those options all the time, only based on some condition - then it would make sense to not transfer the long option list every time, just when it is really needed).

Comment: Yes, but I would suggest using a programming language to do this. Which one do you want to pick?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider populating this dropdown list with Javascript code if it really is that long.

For example, you can make an array of the values/names of the select options you need to create and then iteratively add options elements to a select element. If you give us an idea of the select you're using, we can help you come up with a way. What have you tried thus far?